# Using blending modes in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, blending

How would I recreate this effect using blending modes in Photoshop?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One of the simplest methods would be as follows:

1. Create a base layer and fill it with your desired flat colour.
2. Place your image on the layer above.
3. If the image is not already black and white then go to `Image > Adjustments > Desaturate` to remove the colour.
4. Set the image layer blend mode to MULTIPLY in the layers palette.
5. Place your white text on top of the image.

Done.